# How to edit bootstrap modal inherited CSS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to customize the CSS for a modal on my website like background colors, padding etc. The modal seems to inherit the same CSS as it's parent and when I edit the CSS on my webpage, the overrides are working fine, but the override will not extend to the same element displayed in my modal.

The CSS code that I'm trying to edit is `(.grid-item-header)` and I can simply create an override that works on my webpage, but the exact same `(.grid-item-header)`, which is the same CSS that displays when viewing in developer tools within the modal.  The CSS changes are not being applied though.
So far I've tried `(.modal .grid-item-header)` and `(.modal-content .grid-item-header)`, but I just cannot get it to change.

```
.grid-item-header {background-color: #000000!important;}
.modal .grid-item-header {background-color: #000000!important;}
.modal-content .grid-item-header {background-color: #000000!important;}
```

I wanted the modals header background colors to change, which I did not.

Answer (score 0):

You can override modal popup css by using following code, this is work for me try this once.
put this at the top of page or on conman page

```
@media( min-width: 768px ) {           
.modal-header {
    background-color: black
}
```

}

Comment: Hey thanks for responding but that wont work for my.issue  I have some grid items displaying within a modal  titled . Grid-item-header.  And the modal is supposed to inherit from some parent css which is not extending to the modal for some reason .  Any idea if theres some extra tags i need to add to to my css to override?

Comment: On another forum a developer has suggested that my modal possibly is not loading my css as it does not exist in my dom on page load therefore will not load any css.  Have any ideas how to get my modal to load my css..?

Comment: can you edit your question and share your html code so we can get more idea